# What does the "72" mean for "gcc72-c++"

Tags: c++, gcc, yum

I'm quite familiar with Python / Django but have no knowledge of the C++ world. I'm incorporating a package into a Django app that needs `gcc72-c++` installed. While there is plenty of information online about what g++ is, I'm not quite sure what the "72" refers to. I'm guessing maybe it is version 7.2?

Comment: [gcc 7 series releases](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it refers to GCC [version 7.2](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-7/changes.html)

Comment: What's up with this naming convention? As in why would they put the version number in the middle of the name as compared to the end?

Comment: @Quentin Still waiting for my 2.5 patch update :( I want maracas

Comment: @bones225 Having a prefix is a very normal thing that you probably already have support for. Having a suffix is quite odd and would require special support. For example, a prefix of `/usr/local/bin/gcc72-` could be applied to `gcc`, `c++`, `ld`, and so on. Whereas to do it with a suffix, you'd need both `/usr/local/bin/` and `-gcc72`. Twice as many settings is not great and for things that only supported a prefix you'd be out of luck.

Comment: @bones225 Think of the name as {package}{version}-{module}, as in: the GNU Compiler Collection (gcc), version 7.2 (72), and you need only the c++ compiler from the version 7.2 collection.